# How do I minimise the amount of (and maximise scope of) <sub> </sub>?

Tags: support, markdown

I purpose to minimise my typing of `<sub> </sub>` for efficiency.
So why did my following attempt fail, while I composed [this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/13164/5306)?

`<sub>Source for 1 and 2: Chapter 5 of *[500 French Verbs For Dummies]( http://www.amazon.com/500-French-Verbs-For-Dummies/dp/1118516028)* ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=dU0bAAAAQBAJ&lpg=RA3-PT674&ots=RbBkwDDj-B&dq=transitive%20in%20english%20intransitive%20in%20french&pg=RA3-PT674#v=onepage&q=transitive%20in%20english%20intransitive%20in%20french&f=false))`

`Source for 3 and 4: pp 144-145, pp 146-147 respectively, from [*Correct Your French Blunders]( http://www.amazon.com/Correct-French-Blunders-V%C3%A9ronique-Mazet/dp/0071788247), 2nd Edition*</sub>`

fails, because the following shows that the second paragraph is not subscripted:

> <sub>Source for 1 and 2: Chapter 5 of *[500 French Verbs For Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118516028)* ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=dU0bAAAAQBAJ&lpg=RA3-PT674&ots=RbBkwDDj-B&dq=transitive%20in%20english%20intransitive%20in%20french&pg=RA3-PT674#v=onepage&q=transitive%20in%20english%20intransitive%20in%20french&f=false))</sub>
>
> Source for 3 and 4: pp 144-145, pp 146-147 respectively, from [*Correct Your French Blunders*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071788247), 2nd Edition

Surrounding each paragraph with `<sub> </sub>` solves the problem, but is inefficient.